# Extracting the attributes of one shapefile from the overlap of another using sf

Tags: shapefile, r, attribute-table, overlapping-features, sf

I'm building a movement model with some animal tracking data using a Brownian bridge.

I use the resultant shape to measure how much of it overlaps with protected areas in the region (https://www.protectedplanet.net/country/ZAF).

How can I extract the names from one column (DESIG) of the attribute table in the area of overlap? The attribute table is from the protected planet file.

I'm using R and the `sf` package.

Here's my code:

```
#' load packages
library(tidyverse)
library(move)
library(sf)
library(amt)


#' create a move object 
loc <-
  move(
    x = track$x_,
    y = track$y_,
    time = track$t_,
    proj = CRS( "+proj=aea +lat_1=20 +lat_2=-23 +lat_0=0 +lon_0=25 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs"),
    data = track,
    animal = track$id
  )

#' Now create a dBBMM object
dbbmm <-
  brownian.bridge.dyn(
    object = loc,
    location.error = 20,
    window.size = 31,
    margin = 11,
    raster = 10000
  ) 


#' load in the cleaned version which is in Albers Equal Area
#' this is the taken from the protectedplanet and projected to albers equal area
merged_Africa_tranform <- read_sf("shapefile//merged_Africa_protected_clean.shp")
st_crs(merged_Africa_tranform)

#' what's the area of overlap with the protected areas?
intersection_1_95 <-
  st_intersection(hr_isopleths(dbbmm$layer, level = 0.95),
                  merged_Africa_tranform$geometry)
sum(st_area(intersection_1_95)) / 1e6
```

Here's a sample of my data:

```
track <- structure(list(x_ = c(712247.593901045, 712249.63599448, 712255.771966198, 
712102.501818369, 711909.388675105, 712218.823688024, 712221.896519337, 
712221.899749721, 712215.750856712, 712218.830148765, 712220.862551095, 
712218.813996915, 711592.258625023, 711214.431947071, 705232.573529737, 
704484.660505673, 704574.525571441, 704586.833330272, 704577.582526676, 
703839.386231732, 703841.666220748, 705268.479685813, 703601.261667574, 
703466.806636679, 703228.446726644, 688054.891827718, 688049.142018659, 
688048.879997468, 688047.436483215, 688049.738642599, 688288.470079595, 
688298.728382841, 688283.331520927, 688287.233689746, 688286.411520356, 
693251.060727369, 691895.94267286, 695934.025526456, 704723.981466042, 
704653.085222894, 709478.368513605, 724297.15313828, 737135.325658038, 
743123.408321197, 743107.492642517, 743122.890739821, 743120.844240733, 
743110.6083413, 743101.349741506, 743280.634206655, 741686.447716499, 
740751.050795124, 723565.872650844, 726424.620739435, 742113.896661416, 
763891.653299725, 771306.099600916, 784410.706252694, 784420.984524396, 
784651.673216051, 784652.197601293, 784650.759834527, 786713.465194893, 
776131.160177772, 791978.497428501, 771910.815530644, 777319.113293987, 
823508.490325819, 805173.793218746, 772941.448517303, 765688.241223667, 
765329.9021302, 765336.071269917, 765329.306439016, 765326.653694197, 
765331.229368852, 765963.052544134, 764395.637977457, 764053.609010882, 
771278.483883322, 760497.163530225, 726089.048424295, 715548.19436321, 
686220.606351535, 682643.839100749, 682584.383499343, 682640.734139815, 
682639.730992916, 682643.834403012, 682647.950340522, 682640.765457917, 
682639.718465694, 675928.456251057, 666858.343134657, 657227.261135399, 
622646.808919555, 609555.364548704, 619466.706883248, 619493.70597879, 
619488.561824205), y_ = c(-2897619.44515289, -2897621.63440962, 
-2897624.92738795, -2897498.93857344, -2897683.94074959, -2897649.92496668, 
-2897649.93406015, -2897648.84246531, -2897649.91587326, -2897647.74177681, 
-2897653.20581315, -2897653.19975086, -2896163.41378075, -2895770.36567857, 
-2888073.58655877, -2888910.76395045, -2888920.36769288, -2888914.94243702, 
-2888925.83792632, -2888108.83180636, -2883175.87994117, -2874770.83015247, 
-2858136.04006769, -2858222.11584159, -2858106.49242823, -2827409.03751134, 
-2827628.37797414, -2827630.43368107, -2827627.64191529, -2827628.74527147, 
-2827418.47954615, -2827414.12170738, -2827423.94881294, -2827420.88895306, 
-2827421.76403575, -2832216.16545687, -2822458.43781159, -2822065.22206298, 
-2804439.46921934, -2804855.57191824, -2772317.88886974, -2747820.05265006, 
-2736444.12926355, -2739205.61405997, -2739214.94124829, -2739207.26710426, 
-2739206.15769513, -2739201.71373307, -2739212.7161063, -2739053.04418682, 
-2723051.92607288, -2723903.6891992, -2699199.77940061, -2706451.23477482, 
-2682789.33824453, -2661478.09448947, -2655059.92404033, -2657267.70538243, 
-2657259.97781768, -2657576.71095908, -2657573.10939881, -2657575.4825813, 
-2657295.17114333, -2635355.85939375, -2639186.06073835, -2638488.25825561, 
-2668239.53429157, -2666989.13461943, -2689928.96222006, -2677759.03523352, 
-2669617.1115024, -2667523.0504592, -2667517.52994131, -2667524.36967127, 
-2667512.84632221, -2667520.20547296, -2666056.86632241, -2645303.64873537, 
-2650660.65859159, -2663045.04796073, -2691436.8095449, -2725953.49148845, 
-2714426.12496965, -2714588.2568858, -2711445.14971251, -2711445.53371262, 
-2711455.63848273, -2711447.90058841, -2711446.80721079, -2711441.29383709, 
-2711444.58849718, -2711452.32058259, -2715498.19840585, -2715635.30879854, 
-2702724.33528911, -2696489.11677258, -2663022.66842587, -2632540.6036741, 
-2632608.40346369, -2632615.0522259), t_ = structure(c(1480132500, 
1480135560, 1480138680, 1480141680, 1480144020, 1480146300, 1480148760, 
1480151160, 1480153620, 1480156080, 1480158840, 1480161780, 1480164840, 
1480167900, 1480169880, 1480173480, 1480218360, 1480220940, 1480223640, 
1480226160, 1480229760, 1480233360, 1480236960, 1480240560, 1480244160, 
1480247760, 1480251360, 1480254960, 1480258560, 1480262160, 1480303740, 
1480305660, 1480307640, 1480311240, 1480314840, 1480318440, 1480322040, 
1480325640, 1480329240, 1480332840, 1480336440, 1480340040, 1480343640, 
1480347240, 1480390500, 1480393200, 1480395960, 1480398780, 1480401300, 
1480404900, 1480408500, 1480412100, 1480415700, 1480419300, 1480422900, 
1480426500, 1480430100, 1480433700, 1480475340, 1480478040, 1480481640, 
1480485240, 1480488840, 1480492440, 1480496040, 1480499640, 1480503240, 
1480506840, 1480510440, 1480514040, 1480517640, 1480521240, 1480563480, 
1480567080, 1480570680, 1480574280, 1480577880, 1480581480, 1480585080, 
1480588680, 1480592280, 1480595880, 1480599480, 1480603080, 1480606680, 
1480647600, 1480650780, 1480654380, 1480658100, 1480660020, 1480662000, 
1480663920, 1480667520, 1480671120, 1480674720, 1480678320, 1480681920, 
1480685520, 1480689120, 1480692720), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), id = c("ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2", 
"ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2", 
"ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2", 
"ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2", 
"ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2", 
"ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2", 
"ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2", 
"ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2", 
"ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2", 
"ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2", 
"ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2", 
"ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2")), row.names = c(NA, -100L), class = ("data.frame"))
```

Comment: Are you just looking for `st_intersects`, which returns the row numbers of which polygons intersect which polygons? Use that and then extract the attributes you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment put me on the right track. This worked for me:

```
ID1_parks <- st_intersection(hr_isopleths(dbbmm$ID1, level = 0.95),merged_Africa_tranform)
```

And then I can extract the names etc. of the various parks as follows:

```
ID1_parks$NAME
ID1_parks$DESIG
levels(as.factor(ID1_parks$DESIG))
```